# Apache bench. API with Kerberos Authentication

Tags: kerberos, apachebench, mit-kerberos

My servers have Kerberos Authentication. A sample curl command would look like below.
`curl --negotiate -u : <url>`

Now I need to load test this with Apache Bench. How do I pass the "--negotiate -u :" to ab ?

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Comment: @SreerajKarichery Nope